# SQL Server 2008 : how to use Subquery/CTE for calculated alias columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alias, calculated-field

I have a query I'm trying to build that that basically takes the punch out time for a job and using `DATEADD` and the `TotalTime` column to calculate the punch in time.

What I'm trying to do is use the `ClockOutTime` alias and the `TotalTime` alias.  Being that they are aliases I'm not able to use them in a further calculation which leads me to believe that I may need to reformat it into a subquery or cte, however I'm not a SQL expert and have been unsuccessful trying to get this to work.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    wol.Work_Order_KEY AS WorkOrderKey,
    Contact_Name AS Employee,
    Labor_Date,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Labor_Date, 108) AS ClockOutTime,
    REPLACE(CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), CAST(Hours AS INT) + ((Hours-
    CAST(Hours AS INT)) * .60)) AS VARCHAR), '.', ':') AS TotalTime,
    wol.Asset_ID AS AssetID, 
    al.Group_ID AS GroupID
FROM 
    WorkOrderContacts woc,
    WorkOrderLaborList woll 
JOIN
    WorkOrderList wol ON wol.Work_Order_KEY = woll.Work_Order_KEY 
JOIN
    AssetList al ON wol.Asset_ID = al.Asset_ID
```

Comment: Before you go any further you need to clean this up. Your first two tables are an implicit cross join which is not a good habit. You also are converting to varchar but not specifying the size, this is also a bad habit. You are mixing convert and cast. Not a problem per se but it is certainly confusing to see it done both ways in the same query.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive help!  As I said I'm no expert when it comes to SQL so to be perfectly honest I'm surprised I made it this far lol.  If you have any suggestions on how to clean this up I would be very appreciative.  I didn't know much of what I have here was bad habit/bad form but I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to create an outer query and use the alias there.

```
select * from (select 
    distinct wol.Work_Order_KEY as WorkOrderKey
    ,Contact_Name as Employee
    ,Labor_Date
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Labor_Date,108) as ClockOutTime
    ,replace(cast(convert(decimal(10,2),cast(Hours as int)+((Hours-
    cast(Hours as 
    int))*.60)) as varchar),'.',':') as TotalTime
    ,wol.Asset_ID as AssetID
    ,al.Group_ID as GroupID

FROM 
    WorkOrderContacts woc,
    WorkOrderLaborList woll join 
    WorkOrderList wol on wol.Work_Order_KEY=woll.Work_Order_KEY join 
    AssetList al on wol.Asset_ID=al.Asset_ID) as temp 
    where TotalTime = 'your value'
```

Comment: With some formatting so this is legible this would be a pretty solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation for TotalTime looks a little suspect to me (see my comment in the sql below). And the cross join might be appropriate but often a cross join is not wanted. I attempted to do some formatting to help here. I also changed everything to use convert. Doesn't really matter if you use one or the other but I prefer for a single query to be consistent. Also, not a huge fan of a column named Hours since that is a reserved word in t-sql but it is still manageable. I used a cte in my code but you don't have to do that. You could do a derived table like the other answer here or you could repeat the entire calculation (but that is kind of ugly).

```
with MyCTE as
(
    select 
        distinct wol.Work_Order_KEY as WorkOrderKey
        , Contact_Name as Employee
        , Labor_Date
        , CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Labor_Date,108) as ClockOutTime
        , replace(convert(varchar(10), convert(decimal(10,2), convert(int, Hours) + ((Hours - convert(int, Hours)) * .60))), '.', ':') as TotalTime --should this be dividing by 60 instead of multiplying?
        , wol.Asset_ID as AssetID
        , al.Group_ID as GroupID
    FROM WorkOrderContacts woc
    cross join WorkOrderLaborList woll --do you really want a cross join here or is there an appropriate inner/outer join to be made?
    join WorkOrderList wol on wol.Work_Order_KEY = woll.Work_Order_KEY 
    join AssetList al on wol.Asset_ID = al.Asset_ID
)
select *
from MyCTE
where TotalTime = 'ValueYouAreSearchingFor'
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar, I appreciate the advice and the help with the code.  Will give this a go and report back!